# more efficient if..."or" for arrayformulas in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have an arrayformula where I'm doing ...

```
if((A:A="this")+(A:A="that")+(A:A="something else")...
```

It works fine, but it's unwieldy and gets long. Is there a more efficient way to do this, like some sort of
"if A:A = "this" or "that" or "something else"..."?

Comment: =IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A,"This|That|Anything"),1,0)

Comment: What is your actual goal? There are variety of way. You can use `REGEXMATCH()` as @MattKing suggested. You can also use match like `=ArrayFormula(MATCH(TRANSPOSE({"This","That","Other"}),A1:A10,0))`.

Comment: Regexmatch seems pretty ideal for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may Try `Or` operator

```
=if(OR(B2:B10=100,B2:B10=200,B2:B10=300),"Good","Bad")
```

Or `Switch` function for single expression

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SWITCH(B2:B11,"This",100,"That",50,30))
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with the Switch function, but that seems very useful and easier to read.

Comment: Ya, it is extremely good when you have many condition to select from :)